# To prove for every integer $k >1 $ , $2+2^k \choose r$ is even for all $2 < r \le n=1+2^{k-1}$ , without Lucas' theorem

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Can we prove by induction that for every integer $k >1 $ , $2+2^k \choose r$ is even for all $2 < r \le n=1+2^{k-1}$ ? Or by some divisibility properties of Binomial co-efficients ?

I wanted to start as $2^k \choose r$ $+$ $2$$2^k \choose r-1$ $+$ $2^k \choose r-2$ $=$$ 2+2^k \choose r$ but I don't know whether $2|{2^k \choose m}$ or not ... Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: You ask for all $r$ between $2$ and $n$, but you don't say what $n$ means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is it okay now ?

Comment: It's OK, but it's false. It's certainly false for $r=2+2^k$, but also for $r=2^k$. I think you want the condition to read, $2<r<2^k$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, sorry , actually $2n:=2+2^k$ ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having written

$$\binom{2+2^k}{r} = \binom{2^k}{r} + 2\binom{2^k}{r-1} + \binom{2^k}{r-2},$$

it clearly suffices to see that

$$\binom{2^k}{m} \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$

for $1 \leqslant m \leqslant 2^{k-1}$. Now we can write

$$\binom{2^k}{m} = \frac{(2^k)!}{m!(2^k-m)!} = \frac{2^k}{m}\binom{2^k-1}{m-1},$$

and to conclude that $\binom{2^k}{m}$ is even, we only need to see that the numerator of $\frac{2^k}{m}$ in the reduced form is even. Writing $m = 2^\mu\cdot \rho$ with odd $\rho$, it follows that

$$\binom{2^k}{m} = 2^{k-\mu}\Biggl[\frac{1}{\rho}\binom{2^k-1}{m-1}\Biggr]$$

is even since $m \leqslant 2^{k-1}$ implies $\mu < k$.

Comment: It should be $m \le 1+2^{k-1}$ ; but I think the proof does not change ; if $2^r$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $m$ , then if $r \ge k$ , then $2^k |m  \implies 2^k \le m \le 1+2^{k-1} \implies 2^{k-1} \le 1  $ but $k>1 \implies 2^{k-1}>1$ contradiction ! thus $r \le k-1$ and thanks a lot for the idea of the proof

Comment: I used the symmetry of the binomial coefficients, by which $m \leqslant 2^{k-1}$ suffices, since $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}+r} = \binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}-r}$.